# Unable to get my Histogram to Count Correctly

Tags: java, histogram

I have to count the length of strings in a text file and figure out the frequency of which they appear. I'm able to count the length but my frequency counter is always off and I don't know why.

Say I'm passing in a file with these words:
reinflates,
misorders,
discontinuations,
gastness, and
grousers

My program registers 2 instance of strings of length 8 (correct) and 2 instances of string of length 16 (which is wrong there's only one) and it doesn't even recognize the 10 letter word and the 9 letter word. We're also not allowed to use ArrayList so we have to keep resizing the array ourselves.

Here's my code:

```
int [] histogram = new int[0];

// while loop to read all words into your String[]
// and update all the freq counter for word lengths
while(infile.ready())
{
    String word = infile.readLine();



    if (word.length() >= histogram.length){
        int [] newHistogram = new int [word.length()+1];
        for (int p=0;p<histogram.length;p++){
            histogram[p]=newHistogram[p];
        }
        newHistogram[word.length()]++;
        histogram=newHistogram;
    }

    if (word.length() < histogram.length){
        histogram[word.length()]++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix this,

```
for (int p=0;p<histogram.length;p++)
{
    newHistogram[p]=histogram[p]; //swapped around
}
```

and this,

```
if (word.length() >= histogram.length)
{
....
}
else // introduced
if (word.length() < histogram.length){
        histogram[word.length()]++;
}
```

Comment: Just a quick question though, why do I need the else? I thought it would just see that word.length() is less than histogram.length() and go to that conditional. But apparently my logic is flawed.

Comment: The (new) histogram length will always be `word.length()+1` if the first if-block is entered, and thus it will enter the second block superfluously. By using `if-else` you are "freezing" the check with respect to the original histogram you want to work with, because the decision what if-block to enter happens only once when the CPU reaches this junction in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Edit (thanks to mockinterface): 
You need to change the for loop where you copy the new histogram:

```
for (int p=0;p<histogram.length;p++){
        newHistogram[p] = histogram[p];
}
```

So you copy the old histogram in the new one.

You need to change the second `if` condition to `else`.

If the length of the word is bigger than the length of the histogram:

In the first `if` you create a new histogram of `word.length+1` length, copy the old one there and increase `histogram[word.lenth]`.

Then you reach the second `if` condition and now `histogram.length` is bigger than `word.length` (because you changed it in the previous `if`) so you increase `histogram[word.lenth]` again.

Comment: This is not enough - the copying into newHistogram is wrong as well.